# Symfony2 - ajax/long pool/WS events

Tags: события, symfony2

Доброго времени суток.

**Преамбула**

Есть пользователь. Иногда этого пользователя в режиме "онлайн" необходимо уведомлять о каком-либо событии, которое произошло. Например, получил новое сообщение, в его адрес оставили отзыв и т.д. Есть подобие RIA (Rich Internet Application)

**Теперь по существу**

Задача уведомлять об этих событиях пользователя (если он есть на сайте).

Думаю, что свой велосипед говорить не следует *(в Symfony большое кол-во бандлов)*.
Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей и уже решил ее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужный бандл :)

Спасибо за внимание :)

Answer (score 1):

На хабре была как-то статья по поводу WebSocket-ов http://habrahabr.ru/post/205934/

Но если вы будете их использовать, то далеко не все пользователи со старыми браузерами будут вам рады :)

VK, Facebook, etc. используют Ajax Long Polling. Не уверен, что найдете что-нибудь хорошее из готовых бандлов. Лучше пилить своё. Могу посоветовать модуль Nginx-а для push-а нотификаций клиенту https://github.com/slact/nginx_http_push_module